# ruby driver for mongodb : update method returns Fixnum, not Hash

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm debugging a problem where occasional writes to a mongo collection seem to be failing. As I was going over my error checking code, I found that the update method in the Collection class, seems to be returning a Fixnum instead of a hash.

Here is a code fragment (with debug statements)

```
  begin
    puts "collection type: #{@db_collection.class}"
    status = @db_collection.update(selector, document) 
    puts "[Warn] Database update returned NULL status" unless status

    puts "[Error] Mongo update returned an error: #{status.class}" unless (status == true)
    puts "[Error] Mongo update returned an error: #{status}" unless (status == true)
  rescue => e
    puts "[Warn] Unable to update mongoDB (#{e})"
  end
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

> collection type: Mongo::Collection
>
> [Error] Mongo update returned an error: Fixnum
>
> [Error] Mongo update returned an error: 236

I was expecting the update function to return a true for successful operations and a Hash for fails as per the documentation:

> Returns:
> (Hash, true) — Returns a Hash containing the last error object if acknowledging writes. > Otherwise, returns true.

I'm using version 1.8.0 of the ruby driver.

I'm not sure how to properly check that the writes have occurred correctly. I know that the driver should throw an exception if the write fails but I'm not seeing that happen. I don't know how to properly check the status variable since it's not returning a type I expect.

Thanks in advance for any help here.

Comment: +1 for upgrading, there are a lot of substantial and important fixes in the later 1.8.x series of the driver.

However, that's likely not the issue. What write concern settings are you using for this update?